# Visual Basic PrintDocument Draw a very long string

Tags: vb.net, printdocument

e.Graphics.DrawString(srt, font, brush, point) print a string in a straight line.

what if i have a really long, like real long, by that i mean really long string.
its just gonna print the string over the paper.

how do i make that the string goes to new line when it hits the margin.

Comment: Could you use the drawstring overload that takes a RectangleF parameter?  that will wrap automatically to fit the rectangle you specified

Comment: i never knew such overload lmao, thanks <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a WinForms example with a PictureBox on the form.

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(400, 400)
        Using oFont As Font = New Font("Arial", 16)
            Using grp = Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image)
                Dim LongString As String = "THIS IS A  REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY REALLY LONG STRING"
                grp.DrawString(LongString, oFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200))
                grp.Save()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: For the record, you should use `Brushes.Black` rather than `New SolidBrush(Color.Black)`. If you were going to create your own brush because you needed a custom colour then you should be disposing it after use, which would mean creating it with a `Using` statement. The `Font` object should be disposed as well. ALWAYS dispose objects that you create that support it.

Comment: You are right, I was being lazy. I'll update the code now. Indenting code on here is such a pain it is always tempting to keep examples to the very basic,